# A tag for complete active spaces, multi-reference, multi-configuration

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have gotten a few (good, some excellent) questions about multi-reference, multi-configuration, complete active space, and possibly more related terms, recently. I would guess the grand total is around 25 questions relating to that topic. That doesn't sound too much, but it's also not nothing.

The problem here is, that it doesn't really offer great search terms, and [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry), [computational-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-chemistry), is quite broad. The use of [ab-initio](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ab-initio) is probably also not the best choice. So I would suggest to cluster those questions in a new tag. (When editing one of those, I really had a hard time finding related questions; and overall that would probably be very helpful for a small, but important field.)

And there comes *my problem*: I don't really want to decide all by myself how to call it.

Please discuss and decide with me, or tell me it's a stupid idea. *Answers are appreciated more than comments.*

Comment: Would [Post-Hartree-Fock] still be too broad?

Comment: @pH13-YetanotherPhilipp that would include MBPT, CI, CC, etc. That's too broad for what I intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a [multi-reference](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-reference) tag would be sufficient with [multi-configuration](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-configuration) as a synonym. These tags would be for general discussion of active spaces, choices of references, and multi-reference/configuration variations of electronic structure methods (MCSCF, MR-PT, CASSCF, MR-CI, etc.)

Comment: To those familiar with quantum chemistry, this tag and synonym should be unambiguous. To those unfamiliar, it would probably be mystifying, but hard to confuse with something else unrelated.  It would likely be important to have a good tag excerpt in place from the start, though.

Comment: The change is now life, you'd do me a great favour to check the [tag wikis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tags/multi-reference/info) and extend/correct them. // cc @hBy2Py